# Что означает ошибка: "top level element is not completed"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Перевод строки с ошибкой: "Элемент верхнего уровня не завершен".

Создал файл list_items.xml следующего содержания:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
/>
```

В drawable создал файл item_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@color/selectedColor"
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/transparent"
        />
</selector>
```

AndroidStudio подчеркивает в файле list_items.xml волнистой линией следующее:

```
@drawable/item_selector
```

С чем может быть связана эта ошибка?

Comment: У меня с вашими файлами никаких ошибок нет. Попробуйте сделать ```Build -> Clean Project``` в Android Studio.

Comment: пробовал, не помогает. Что-то случилось с самой Студией (мне кажется), т.к. сначала подчеркиваний не было.

Comment: Попробуйте проделать то, что предлагают в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30768229/3069565)  `alt + enter ->  "Uninject language/reference"`

Comment: Теперь все горит красным.